# where to write on click event using java in android

Tags: java, android

Hello I recently updated may ADT and and now I am developing new app using eclipse. so i want to know where to write setOnclickListner event. I want to open another activity on click button. I tried various combinations but it's gives me error every time. my eclipse Version: 8.1.2.201302132326  please tell me where i can write code??????

after adding  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); it gives an Error and application will unfortunately stooped.

I also remove some code and run it but it does not worked.

eg.

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

        }
```

and

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
        {

            public PlaceholderFragment() 
            {



            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                        false);

                return rootView;
            }

        }
```

this code remove from coding but it's not worked.

and in that when i am creating new blank activity then there is fragment activity.xml will created automatically and I want make GUI changes in fragment activity.xml file. If I made changes in activity.xml then it gives error.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance..

here is may code which is automatically generated...

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            if (savedInstanceState == null) 
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

            }


        }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
            {

                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
            {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            /**
             * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
             */
            public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
            {

                public PlaceholderFragment() 
                {



                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                            false);

                    return rootView;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: try to extends FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: You can remove the Fragment code and make changes in activity.xml, and use setOnclickListner inside onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

you should put the button fragment container,

so,you need to access your button you should specify like this because your placehold fragment inflate the layout of `fragment_container.xml`

```
Button b1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnclickListener(this);
```

in this case implements the `onClickLiistener` your class,Automatically `onclick` will override in your class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            if (savedInstanceState == null) 
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

            }


        }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
            {

                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
            {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            /**
             * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
             */
            public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
            {

                public PlaceholderFragment() 
                {



                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                            false);
                            final Activity contect=getActivity();
                Button b1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in=new Intent(contect,YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }) ;

                    return rootView;
                }

            }

        }
```

put the button in fragment_main,move to the some other activity

Otherwise remove the fragment and extends the activity also remove the appcompat_v7 libraries from the code and project.

Remove the libraries Properties-->Android--> from below remove it